# dplyr: Error "non-numeric argument to binary operator" when attempting to mutate column

Tags: r

Trying to `mutate` and `pivot_longer` a dataframe column raises the error

> non-numeric argument to binary operator.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Below is the code in use.

```
DF <- mydata4 %>% 
  mutate('S-25-(OH)-D3' = 'S-25-(OH)-D3 (nmol/L)'/1000) %>%
  pivot_longer(.,-`Date of examination`, names_to = "variable",values_to = "value")
```

Comment: That whole bit is the code, it is my first time on the platform, I apologize in advance for any confusion.

Comment: Note that You should include the  a sample of `mydat4` and the output you expect from that sample

Answer (score 0):

You have your variables in quotes. See [10.2 here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tibbles.html?q=syntactic#creating-tibbles) re non-syntactic names.

You could use backticks instead per example two below, or clean the names first, e.g. make them snake_case per example three:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)

tibble(`S-25-(OH)-D3 (nmol/L)` = c(1000:1010)) |> 
  mutate('S-S-25-(OH)-D3' = 'S-25-(OH)-D3 (nmol/L)' / 1000)
#> Error in `mutate()`:
#> ! Problem while computing `S-S-25-(OH)-D3 = "S-25-(OH)-D3
#>   (nmol/L)"/1000`.
#> Caused by error in `"S-25-(OH)-D3 (nmol/L)" / 1000`:
#> ! non-numeric argument to binary operator

tibble(`S-25-(OH)-D3 (nmol/L)` = c(1000:1010)) |> 
  mutate(`S-S-25-(OH)-D3` = `S-25-(OH)-D3 (nmol/L)` / 1000)
#> # A tibble: 11 × 2
#>    `S-25-(OH)-D3 (nmol/L)` `S-S-25-(OH)-D3`
#>                      <int>            <dbl>
#>  1                    1000             1   
#>  2                    1001             1.00
#>  3                    1002             1.00
#>  4                    1003             1.00
#>  5                    1004             1.00
#>  6                    1005             1.00
#>  7                    1006             1.01
#>  8                    1007             1.01
#>  9                    1008             1.01
#> 10                    1009             1.01
#> 11                    1010             1.01

tibble(`S-25-(OH)-D3 (nmol/L)` = c(1000:1010)) |> 
  clean_names() |> 
  mutate(s_25_oh_d3 = s_25_oh_d3_nmol_l / 1000)
#> # A tibble: 11 × 2
#>    s_25_oh_d3_nmol_l s_25_oh_d3
#>                <int>      <dbl>
#>  1              1000       1   
#>  2              1001       1.00
#>  3              1002       1.00
#>  4              1003       1.00
#>  5              1004       1.00
#>  6              1005       1.00
#>  7              1006       1.01
#>  8              1007       1.01
#>  9              1008       1.01
#> 10              1009       1.01
#> 11              1010       1.01
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>